# content takes all the space between header and footer

Tags: html, css

My simple layout contains header, main section and footer. Footer pushed to bottom of a page. And I want main section to take all the space between header and footer.
 Here is what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/5d3m9/ 
HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
   <header>header</header>
   <div class="main">lorem2000 </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <footer>@Copyright</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    height: 150px;
    background: orange;
}
.wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main {
    background: #00eaea;
    padding-bottom: 32767px;
    margin-bottom: -32767px;
}
.clear {
    height: 50px;
}
footer {
    background: #dadada;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Is there any other/better way to achieve this? (without `padding-bottom: 32767px; margin-bottom: -32767px;`)

Comment: Seems to work for me? Why do you want to get rid of the padding-bottom and margin-bottom?

Comment: just interested, maybe Im making a bicycle here and there is a lot easier way

Comment: What if the content doesn't fit?  Should it scroll?

Comment: dow, sorry, I get it like overflow: scroll for main >< it means it should scroll, @gilly3, sorry)(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the following style to `.main`

```
.main {
    background: #00eaea;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5d3m9/1/

Comment: I can't see main on my small screen. Maybe that's OK since OP said not scroll bars needed? That seems a bit weird

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry - it should scroll